# как сохранить файл в mongodb cloud?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, flask

у меня есть приложение в котором я хочу сделать возможность загрузки песен. Я пытался сохранять данные в mongo db cloud, но у меня ничего не выходит.
я делаю такой запрос с front-end части:

```
  const sendFile = () => {

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/music', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {

        },
        body: input
    })
        .then(r => r)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })

    setShow(false)
}
```

в input лежит сам файл, который пользователь выбрал с помощью инпута
вот код на flask который должен отправлять файл в бд

```
@app.route('/music', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
        if request.method == 'GET':
                all_seeds = list(music.find({}))
                return json.dumps(all_seeds, default=json_util.default)
        else:
                profile_image = request.files['file']
                mongo.save_file(profile_image.filename, profile_image)
                music.insert(profile_image)
```

файлы естественно не загружаются и возникает ошибка 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: а как догадаться к чему относится profile_image? и почему картинка профиля -- это музыка?

Comment: я просто пытался сохранить картинку вместо аудио файла

Comment: a `music` это что? что в переменной?

Comment: music это просто название коллекции db = cluster.multiTask;
music = db.music; вообще я даже не знаю правильно ли я post запрос вообще делаю

Comment: посмотрите документацию, что принимает `insert`; и что возвращает `request.files['file']`; посмотрите, как писать в лог для отладки; где логи;

Comment: у меня возникает проблема именно с отправкой файла, когда я отправляю обычные json данные, то все работает

Comment: и какая в логе ошибка?

Comment: у меня либо возникает ошибка 400 плохой запрос либо ошибка 500

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо выяснить:

- где документация на сервер (flask)
- где смотреть **лог** сервера
- как записать в этот лог значение переменной в ходе обработки запроса
- какую библиотеку для свюзи с монго вы используете
- где у нее документация
- что в документации написано про `request.files['file']`, `cluster.multiTask`, `save_file`, `insert`
- значения каких типов ожидают на вход эти методы, и что они возвращают
- в чем отличия удачного и неудачного запроса по логам (добавив запись значений)

Пробуйте.
Если где-то застрянете -- добавляйте в вопрос то, что выяснили и где застряли.